# AngularJs one page app ng-view trouble

Tags: angularjs

I am brand new to AngularJs and after following some tutorials I decided to try to implement a one page app into one of my projects. I have it working but I had one question about this code. Could I change what is shown on the first page before they navigate to anything? I don't want it shown on every page just when they first land on it before clicking any links.

```js
var app=angular.module('single-page-app',['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
          .when('/',{
                templateUrl: 'home.html'
          })
          .when('/about',{
                templateUrl: 'about.html'
          });
});
app.controller('cfgController',function($scope){

    /*      
    Here you can handle controller for specific route as well.
    */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="single-page-app">
 <div ng-controller="cfgController">
    <div>
     <nav>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/about">About us</a></li>
          </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
    <br/>
    <div ng-view>
    <!--
        This DIV loads templates depending upon route.
   -->
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

The pages load fine and if I try to add something to the index.html under ng-view it doesn't show up on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put the content to show up when a user first hits your site under in your "home.html" page which is linked to your "/" route for "ng-view". When a user clicks a link, they will be taken to a new route, and the code/ will be replaced by the route they selected.

Comment: I would like to make something show on this intial landing page, before they click any links.

Comment: Do you have anything in your 'home.html' file?

Comment: Oh boy I feel a little bit dumb, I forgot to put content in the home.html file. Thank you for that.